# Where is the download link for 10.04 desktop?

Tags: 10.04, downloads

I am looking for an older version of ubuntu.  Please tell me where I can find the download link for 10.04 desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Old versions of Ubuntu can be found [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).

Here's a link to [10.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.4/).

Answer (score 3):

All the recent Ubuntu releases (starting from 8.04) are available [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2):

http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/

32 bit :

PC (Intel x86) desktop CD

64 bit :

64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD

Answer (score 0):

32 bit  download link
http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-server-i386.iso

download starts automatically.

Comment: NB: That download link is for the Server edition; the Desktop edition of 10.04 is EOL and no longer supported.